# The best way to share git hooks

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on setting up a pre-push/pre-receive Git hook to enforce validation rules for branch names in my GitHub Enterprise repository. I want to ensure that branch names meet specific criteria before being pushed to the remote repository.

How can I configure a pre-push/pre-receive Git hook to validate branch names before pushing to the remote repository on GitHub Enterprise?

What would be the best practices for defining and enforcing rules for branch names in this context?

I've researched a bit and found some examples, but I'd like to hear your insights and experiences regarding branch name validation using Git hooks in the GitHub Enterprise environment.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Grouping multiple questions in one post is rarely a good idea. Could you consider splitting these? (In order to have **one** main question clearly identified on each page)

Comment: Asking opinions on best ways is also discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the best practice is to use a `pre-receive` hook (which you can use on GitHub Enterprise Server, but not GitHub Enterprise Cloud), or use some sort of other server-side validation, such as a protected main branch with CI jobs on pull request that reject undesired commits or branch names.

You could also use a forking model on your repository where developers can create whatever branches they want on their own forks, but must meet some criteria to be merged.  This is also the purview of a CI system.

A `pre-push` hook is run client side, and is trivially bypassed without any indication that that's happened.  That's why [the Git FAQ mentions that it's not an effective control](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks) and that effective controls must happen on the server side.  You can provide one if you like, but developers are not compelled to use it, and you should typically make it opt-in.  Your more experienced developers will generally appreciate having more flexibility with hooks due to the fact that they may have their own configuration that they themselves want to use.

Since hooks can execute arbitrary code, there is no way to automatically install them when cloning or fetching the repository, since that would be an arbitrary code execution vulnerability.  You can provide a script that copies them into place on request, as I mentioned above, which developers can use (or not).

If you're using a `pre-receive` hook, you will get the triplet of `OLD-OID NEW-OID REFNAME` on standard input.  Thus, you'll typically want a structure like this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read oldoid newoid ref
do
    if echo "$newoid" | grep -qsE '^0+$'
    then
        # deletion.
        continue
    elif echo "$oldoid" | grep -qsE '^0+$'
    then
        # creation
        continue
    else
        # update
        continue
    fi
done
```

You will probably not care about users deleting inappropriately named refs, so you'll probably want to reject refs in the creation and update cases based on whatever criteria you like.

Note that as I mentioned above, GitHub Enterprise Cloud doesn't offer `pre-receive` hooks, since hooks can execute arbitrary code and GitHub, for security reasons, doesn't want to do that on behalf of users.  Thus, an alternative approach will be required in that case.

Comment: Okay - we use GitHub enterprise cloud. does that mean that there are not way to validate branch names before it is pushed to remote? I thought about using pre-receive but it is on the server side as you said....

what about using client side hooks and then make bash script which moves the hooks from a self made folder and move it the .git/hooks folder. So when you clone the repository you should run that script manual, but you only have to do that once?

Comment: GHEC doesn't have pre-receive hooks, so I'm not aware of a way to reject branch names before they're pushed to the remote.  Client side hooks can always be bypassed without any detection of that fact.  It's easy to just delete the hooks, or in some cases, there's a `--no-verify` option to bypass it.  Your best bet is to simply protect your main branch and reject PRs (via CI) that use an inappropriately named branch.